# Why mocking a private method enters method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermockito

I'm using PowerMockito to mock a private method in my test.

```
validator = spy(new CommentValidator(form, request));
PowerMockito.when(
        validator,
        method(CommentValidator.class, "isCaptchaValid",
        HttpServletRequest.class))
    .withArguments(Mockito.any())
    .thenReturn(true);
```

When I run the test I get `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException` with a `NullPointerException` at the second line of the `isCaptchaValid` method, which looks like this:

```
private boolean isCaptchaValid(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Captcha captcha =
        (Captcha) request.getSession().getAttribute("attribute");
    if (captcha == null) {
        log.debug(String.format("O valor do captcha da sessão esta nulo. IP: [%s]",
            IPUtil.getReaderIp(request)));
        return false;
    }
    if (captcha.isInputValid(
            request.getParameter("captcha").toString().toUpperCase())) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public final Boolean isInputValid(String pInput) {

    if (getPuzzle() == null) {
        if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOGGER.debug("puzzle is null and invalid. Will return Boolean.FALSE");
        }
        return Boolean.FALSE;
    }

    Boolean returnValue = verifyInput(pInput);
    if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
        LOGGER.debug("Validation of puzzle: " + returnValue);
    }
    disposePuzzle();

    return returnValue;
}
```

Why is the method's implementation being considered if I'm mocking its behavior? Is there a way to avoid that? The reason why I need to mock it is because I can't provide the `Captcha` object.

Comment: Are you sure you're declaring that correctly?  [The documents](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13) show differently; you should supply the instance, the method name, and its arguments.

Comment: Hm, I don't see anything wrong in what you posted. However, there are some pitfalls to avoid when mocking, especially when mocking private methods. You'll probably have to supply a runnable example (SSCCE, http://sscce.org/ ).

Comment: As @Makoto has pointed out you should partially mock the method like this: `PowerMockito.doReturn(true).when(validator, "isCaptchaValid", mockHttpServletRequest);` where `mockHttpServlcetRequest` is an instance and not the class - For _HttpServletRequest_ you might have a look at springs `MockHttpServletRequest` class or its builder. Using `spy` will leave the method body intact while using `mock` will usually replace the body with `return null` -  that's why your call produces the NPE on `request.getSession()` invocation

Comment: Makoto and Roman, check the [API](https://powermock.googlecode.com/svn-history/r1813/docs/powermock-1.5/apidocs/org/powermock/api/mockito/PowerMockito.html). `static
<T> WithOrWithoutExpectedArguments<T>
 when(Class<?> cls, Method method)`. I need the `WithOrWithoutExpectedArguments` interface in order to use `.withArguments`.

Comment: @sleske, I really enjoyed the link you sent. Never had seen that. However, it looks to me that I followed that by instinct. What exactly you think I could add to the OP? Maybe the `Captcha.isInputValid` method? I'll add it right away. Let me know if there's anything else I could add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem solved**

By calling

```
PowerMockito.when(
        validator,
        method(CommentValidator.class, "isCaptchaValid",
        HttpServletRequest.class))
    .withArguments(Mockito.any())
    .thenReturn(true);
```

first the method itself is validated by `PowerMockito` and therefore `NPE` is very likely to be found.

In order to avoid that, you need to invert that logic.

```
doReturn(true).when(validator, "isCaptchaValid", any(HttpServletRequest.class));
```

It makes `PowerMockito` disregard the method's body and immediately return what you want.